# New column in select will not mask column of the same name in having clause and sqlite won't warn

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got this query in sqlite

```
select kvadrat, datum, count(distinct kontrola) as pocet
from b
group by kvadrat, datum
having pocet > 1
```

The problem was that `pocet` was actually a column in table b and I didn't notice, and the `having` clause was using the table column instead of the newly derived column specified in select clause.

So far so good, but sqlite should at least issue any warning, right?

**EDIT: I have repoted this as a bug**

PS: I am using sqlite using sqldf package in R (version 0.4-7.1). Package RSQLite 0.11.4. According to its description the SQLite engine should be version 3.7.17.

Comment: Do you have a question?  Use `having count(distinct kontrola) > 1` to get around this issue.

Comment: you cannot use alias name in same select statement except order by. So engine will consider the existing column to filter in having clause

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . Your comment is specific to SQLite.  Some databases do allow the use of aliases in the `having` clause.

Comment: Maybe SQLite should have issued a warning; but that's something to take up with the developer's surely? What can we do about it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Oops i don't know that ty..

Comment: I have already reported this as a bug.

Comment: Why should it issue a warning?

Comment: @Lennart it will help the developer. This is a gotcha, something you might really crash on. There are warnings for less serious things...

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand what you want it to warn about, is it that you renamed a derived column to the name of a column that potentially could have been referred to in the select clause?

Comment: @Lennart, no. I would like it to warn that the variable `pocet` in the having clause does not refer to the pocet defined in select clause, but is masked by column `pocet` in table `b`. So if you remove the `having` clause, there would be no warning.

Comment: I see, but renaming (as ...) is done after having so the "variable" pocet does not even exist at that time.

Comment: @Lennart wrong! Renaming (as..) is done after `where` but *before* `having` (this is the reason why having exists, otherwise, you could do everything in `where` :-)). If you rename `pocet` to something else it works as expected.

Comment: No, that's not correct. The order of evaluation is FROM, JOIN, WHERE, GROUP, HAVING, SELECT (rename). HAVING will accept aggregation (such as COUNT(1) ) in predicates (since it is evaluated after GROUPING) whereas WHERE will not.

Comment: Regarding renaming to something else, nothing prevents the DBMS to change the order of evaluation as long as it preserve the semantics of the query.